Formula for circular or looped combinations?
I am creating square tiles for a game. Each side of each tile must match up with the same type of side on the adjacent tile. I am trying to calculate how many unique tiles I will need depending on how many types of sides I decide to create. Tiles can be rotated but not flipped.
This essentially creates looped combinations where the order matters but starting location does not. For example, 1234, would be counted redundant with 2341, 3412, and 4123 because you could rotate the tile and it would still be the same instance, but 1234 would be different from 4321 because the tiles cannot be flipped.
this is different from circular permutations because elements can be repeated. 1111 would be a valid tile as would 1232 or 1122.
If I use 1 side type I obviously only have 1 combination: 1111. if I have 2 side types I counted a total of 6 unique combinations: 1111, 1112, 1122, 1212, 1222, and 2222. I think I counted 24 unique combinations if I have 3 unique side types, but this is where things start to get a little cumbersome for me.
I haven't been able to find a formula to explain the pattern, nor was I able to find the answer online. Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to math.SE! I have no idea why someone voted to close; this is a fine question as far as I'm concerned, don't let it get you down!

These are called necklaces. Formally we can consider a set of $q$ beads, and put them together to form strings of beads of length $n$, except that we consider two strings to define the same necklace if they are cyclic permutations of each other. It's a little difficult to explain how to count these from scratch, but it can be done using Burnside's lemma, and the answer is that the number of necklaces of length $n$ using $q$ beads is
$$N(q, n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \varphi(d) q^{\frac{n}{d}}$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function and the notation means that the sum runs over all divisors of $n$. For necklaces of length $n = 4$ (which correspond to, say, coloring the sides of a square, which sounds like what you're doing) this gives
$$N(q, 4) = \frac{\varphi(1) q^4 + \varphi(2) q^2 + \varphi(4) q}{4} = \boxed{ \frac{q^4 + q^2 + 2q}{4} }$$
and you can check that this reproduces your examples after plugging in $q = 1, 2, 3$; in particular your count for $q = 3$ is correct.
For small values of $n$ you can do some casework to show that the above formula is correct by hand without having to work through the general argument. Before considering cyclic permutations, there are $q^4$ strings of beads of length $4$. We can divide these up into three different cases depending on how they behave with respect to rotation:

Every rotation is the same (for example $1111$). This case happens $q$ times, one for each type of bead, and each of these strings corresponds to a unique necklace, so we get $q$ necklaces in this case.

Every second rotation is the same (for example $1212$), but not every rotation is the same. In this case the string must have the form $abab$ where $a \neq b$, so this case happens $q(q - 1)$ times, and since $abab$ is the same necklace as $baba$ we get $\frac{q(q - 1)}{2} = {q \choose 2}$ necklaces in this case.

No rotation is the same (for example $1211$). This is the complement of the previous two cases so it happens $q^4 - q - q(q - 1) = q^4 - q^2$ times, and each of the corresponding necklaces corresponds to $4$ strings so we get $\frac{q^4 - q^2}{4}$ necklaces in this case.


It's a nice exercise to check that these are the only possibilities. Adding up the cases we get a total count of $\boxed{ q + {q \choose 2} + \frac{q^4 - q^2}{4} }$ necklaces which simplifies to the above.

Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.
